# git: How do I delete only fifth commit

Tags: git

I have for example 10 commits. I want to delete fifth commit forever. How do I delete only fifth commit.

Comment: See also "amending" nth commit; http://superuser.com/questions/229317/how-to-amend-the-n-th-commit-before

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say your commit has SHA1 `abc123`, you can do for example:

```
git rebase -i abc123^
```

delete the first line, save and quit. This will replay the whole history since that commit, so it can create conflicts, which you'll need to resolve by hand.

Answer (score 4):

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

In the text editor that comes up delete the rogue commit, then save and exit.

You may find a [guide to interactive rebase](http://help.github.com/rebase/) helpful